# Number of child nodes in a specific level in a non-binary tree

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method

```
 public int getNumberOfChildNodes(int level)
```

which would return a number of child nodes in a specific level. Explanation in the picture below: [Level 1 should return 2 (B and C) and level 2 should return 5 (D, E, F, G, H)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiFes.png)

I already created a code which returns height of the tree and which returns the number of all child nodes, however I am clueless how to find out the number of childNodes only on specific level. Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tree {

private String name;
private List<Tree> childNodes = new ArrayList<Tree>();

public Tree(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void addChildNode(Tree childNode) {
    childNodes.add(childNode);
}


public int getNumberOfChildNodes() {
    int result = 0;
    for (Tree childNode : childNodes){
        result += childNode.getNumberOfChildNodes();
   }
    return result + childNodes.size();
}

/*

public int getNumberOfChildNodes(int level) {
    int result = 0;        
    for (Tree childNode : childNodes) {
        result += childNode.getNumberOfChildNodes();
 }
    return result + childNodes.size();    }
*/

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in regards to that method? And why did it not work?

Comment: I have tried using method getHeight, however it was such a poor attempt that it's not worth sharing. I am clueless with this one.

Comment: @chevybow nevermind, shared my attempt. I have edited the post, but it's pretty much broken at all inputs.

Comment: I think you don't want to use childNode.getHeight.  You care about the depth from the root of the tree.  I would pass down the current depth, increment it at each recursive level, and stop when it reaches the level you're interested in

Comment: @Steve how would I do that? Sorry, I'm still trying to learn recursion..

Comment: I think @Omri's answer is doing what I'm talking about

Comment: Consider doing some reading on tree traversals. 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this recursive function:

```
public int getNumberOfChildNodes(int level) {
    if(level == 0)
        return childNodes.size();

    int numOfChildren = 0;
    for (Tree childNode : childNodes) {
        numOfChildren += childNode.getNumberOfChildNodes(level-1);
    }

    return numOfChildren ;
}
```

The idea is to scan each level. And for each recursive call we decrease the level by 1. so when `level==0` it means we are in a node at the level we wanted and we will return the `size()` of this node.

### Edit

In this solution I assumed that the level of each node is the distance from the root (i.e root it at level 0 and it's children are at level 1 and so on).

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing I was thinking about

Comment: ...but I think 'numberOfChildren' should be 'result' - don't think this code will work as is since 'result' isn't defined.

Comment: Could you edit it please to not count the root as a level 1?

Comment: @J.Doe, I think just change the test at the top to "if (level==1)"

Comment: @J.Doe as far as I know it does not count the root as level 1. If you call the function for the root level it should look like `getNumberOfChildNodes(0)` and it should work. If you count the root as level 1 and not 0, just change the condition to be `if(level==1)`